# How to show the different contents to the customer and admin in the new order email?

Tags: magento2.2.2, order-email, multi-website

Please help.

I need to do this for only one website as I have multiwebsite functionality in my project.

Comment: In that case you need to replicate order email functionality in custom module and to send after order place event. In observer you have to check order place on which website. You will get this information in observer.

Comment: user55548, can you please help me to share some code. That would be a great help.